# My program returns 21144 instead of 21124, why?

Tags: c#

Number letter counts
Problem 17 
If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.

If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words, how many letters would be used?

NOTE: Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen) contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in compliance with British usage.

Tried comparing some numbers to strings they all matched.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    static int n = 1000;
    static List<int> letterCountCache = new List<int>();
    public static void Main()
    {
        long t = 0;
        letterCountCache.Add(0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i ++)
        {
            letterCountCache.Add(GetLetterCount(i));
            t += letterCountCache[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(t);
        Console.WriteLine(letterCountCache[70] + " " + "seventy".Length);

    }

    static int GetLetterCount(int i)
    {
        if (letterCountCache.Count > i)
            return letterCountCache[i];
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                return "one".Length;
            case 2:
                return "two".Length;
            case 3:
                return "three".Length;
            case 4:
                return "four".Length;
            case 5:
                return "five".Length;
            case 6:
                return "six".Length;
            case 7:
                return "seven".Length;
            case 8:
                return "eight".Length;
            case 9:
                return "nine".Length;
            case 10:
                return "ten".Length;
            case 11:
                return "eleven".Length;
            case 12:
                return "twelve".Length;
            case 13:
                return "thirteen".Length;
            case 14:
                return "fourteen".Length;
            case 15:
                return "fifteen".Length;
            case 16:
                return "sixteen".Length;
            case 17:
                return "seventeen".Length;
            case 18:
                return "eighteen".Length;
            case 19:
                return "nineteen".Length;
        }
        if (i >=20 && i <=29)
            return "twenty".Length + GetLetterCount(i % 10);
        if (i >=30 && i <=39)
            return "thirty".Length + GetLetterCount(i % 10);
        if (i >= 40 && i <= 49)
            return "forty".Length + GetLetterCount(i % 10);
        if (i >=50 && i <= 59)
            return "fifty".Length + GetLetterCount(i % 10);
        if (i > 80 && i < 89)
            return "eighty".Length + GetLetterCount(i % 10);
        if (i >= 60 && i <= 99)
            return GetLetterCount(i % 10) + "ty".Length + GetLetterCount(i / 10);
        if (i == 1000)
            return "onethousand".Length;
        if (i % 100 == 0)
            return  GetLetterCount(i / 100) + "hundred".Length;
        return GetLetterCount(i / 100) + "hundred".Length + "and".Length + GetLetterCount(i % 100);
    }
}
```

The correct results apparently is 21124. Mine returns 21144. Anyone know why?

Comment: i'm guessing it is your stop condition on your loop.

Comment: Shouldn't `"onethousand"` be *two* words? `"one thousand"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko He removed the space so he doesn't have to count it. Just like any hyphens.

Comment: You don't have a return string.empty.length for 0

Comment: @DanielBrughera spotted that, but it never happens because it's caught by the 'cache' at the top, a zero entry is added for index 0 before the methods runs.

Comment: @CharlesMager right, i missed it

Answer (score 8):

Missing equality signs in condition:

```
if (i >= 80 && i <= 89)
        return "eighty".Length + GetLetterCount(i % 10);
```

Comment: Without this, you get `eightty` and `eighttynine`. Which incorrectly counts 2 extra letters for each 100 numbers. So given 1000 numbers, it accounts for the answer being wrong by +20.